# SQL Statement Error, inner joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have to join 3 tables with an sql

I need to to output the 
- testID which is in the table test and testLink
- testTotal which is in the table test
- testScore which is in the table testLink

And i need to do this by entering it for a single student which has a student ID, the student ID is present in the student table and the testLink table

```
SELECT testLink.testID, testLink.testScore, test.testTotal
FROM students
LEFT JOIN testLink
ON students.studentID=testLink.studentID
WHERE students.studentID ='1'
ORDER BY students.studentID
```

This is what i have till now but it doest output the testTotal for each test.

How do i link the table test and output the test total in this one sql statement

Comment: Please clarify: what exactly do you want to see? the total number of points per student? The total number of points per test per student?

Comment: Where's the join to your `test` table?  The query above will definitely generate an error because `test.testTotal` does not exist.

Comment: Where's test in all of this? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a join with TEST table, you need to add a INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN with test table.

And the LEFT JOIN gives you null value from tables testLink and test if studentID exist in students table but not in testLink or test table

Comment: can i add more than one join in the sql

Comment: Yes , you  can add

Comment: whats the right syntax to add it, where in the statement can i link, can you show me

Comment: ON test.id=testLink.id , to join test and testLink, you need to put the right Id to join test and testLink

Comment: SELECT testLink.testID, testLink.testScore, test.testTotal
FROM students
LEFT JOIN testLink
ON students.studentID=testLink.studentID
WHERE students.studentID ='1'
ORDER BY students.studentID

Comment: `
SELECT testLink.testID, testLink.testScore, test.testTotal
FROM students
LEFT JOIN testLink
ON students.studentID=testLink.studentID
LEFT JOIN test
ON test.id=testLink.testId
WHERE students.studentID ='1'
ORDER BY students.studentID
`

sorry i need your schema to put the right Ids, so you need just to put the rigth IDs to join test and testLink